# Node still taking up the same space after scale transform effect applied

Tags: java, javafx

sorry if this is duplicate I couldn't find anything on it.

I am trying to resize a node using `javafx.scene.transform.Scale` and when resized, the node is visually smaller but it appears to still take up the same amount of space on the parent node.

An example can be seen here:

Un-scaled
[image: un-scaled node]

Scaled
[image: scaled node]

As can be seen the `Sample Button` has not moved up to fill the empty space.
The code used to generate the scenario is as follows:

```java
Pane buttons = new Pane(gridPane);
Scale scale = new Scale(0.3, 0.3, 0, 0);
buttons.getTransforms().add(scale);

Button sampleButton = new Button("Sample Button");
sampleButton.setMinSize(410, 60);
sampleButton.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 25));

VBox vbox = new VBox(buttons, sampleButton);
```

Please note that I am happy to use another method to scale the node and that I **cannot** just simply make a smaller button instead of scaling.

I am using Java 13

Comment: Wrap the `gridPane` in a `Group`, instead of a `Pane`, and apply the scale to the `GridPane` (not the `Group`).

Comment: Absolute legend! It worked, thank you so much!

Comment: (Or, I guess, just wrap the `Pane` in a `Group`: `VBox vbox = new VBox(new Group(buttons), sampleButton);`, but then the `Pane` seems redundant)

Comment: See the [docs for `Group`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Group.html): "Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group. Such transforms and effects will NOT be included in this Group's layout bounds, however ***if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds***." (my emphasis)

Comment: True, the `Pane` is a little redundant haha